# woocommerce product attributes

Tags: plugins, hooks

Forgive me if someone has asked this before, but i am trying to get some attributes displayed next to displayed content of product. I see the hook `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` that displayed few attributes but not all. The `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` let me back to directory structure in woo/templates/single-products/filename which is just

```
  if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $product;
if ($product->is_on_sale()) :

apply_filters('woocommerce_sale_flash', '<span class="onsale">'.__( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ).'</span>', $post, $product); ?>
endif;
```

Now i am lost, where do i go from here? How do i add my attributes to my product-catalog and single product page? Where do i go from the `apply_filters`? How do i find the generated html for the attributes?

Comment: I don't see how the sale-flash.php template has anything to do with product attributes. I'm not sure your question is in scope, but try clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A look at the [documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) or the source is always helpful. I guess, the correct file to refer to would have been `product-attributes.php`. For getting the product attributes this is available: [`get_attribute()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1121-1149) ; to list them [`list_attributes()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1242-1252) can be used, which makes use of the `product-attributes.php` template. You can use those and then hook into the fitting one to display the attributes. To learn more about hooks give the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) a good thorough read.